# Akka Streams, how to 'mock' source based on configuration

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm looking for suggestion for this scenario: I have multiple sources that I want to merge at some point and I would like to enable or disable them according to configuration. For instance, in the following example a tick source:

```
sources {
  "enableTickSource": false
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like this

```
if (config.enableTickSource) {
  Source.tick(..., T)
} else {
  Source.never[T]
}
```

The problem is that the [tick](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/tick.html) source is of type `Source[T, Cancellable]` while the [never](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/never.html#never) source is of type `Source[T, NotUsed]`, so I would have to add more logic afterwards while I would love these two sources to be transparently interchangeable.

Potential solutions I haven't fully explored:

- Discard the `Cancellable` materialized value
- Map the materialized value to something else, like

```
Source.never[T]
  .mapMaterializedValue(_ => fakeCancellable)
```

- Using options, like returning `Option[Source[..., Cancellable]]` and return `None` in the second case (I feel this would make code much more complex later)

Is there a recipe or best practice for this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What's wrong with `mapMaterializedValue`? The map will not be called anyway, so it's only about adjusting types.

Comment: I would discard the `Cancellable` materialised value if you don't plan on using it, or indeed create a "fake" one for the `never` case. As said by Mateusz, no much to worry as this is just to have a consistent type.